# How to send an input phrase without using quotes

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I would like to call a script like so:

```
ask.ps1 what is foo
```

as opposed to

```
ask.ps1 "what is foo"
```

and then have the "ask.ps1" script treat all the words (which can be a random number of words) as one string

ask.ps1

---

```
param(
     $inputString = <???>
)
write-host ("Received input: " + $inputString)
```

is this possible?

Comment: mind as well not use a `param` block and use `$args` instead: `write-host ("Received input: " + $args)`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! :-) thanks, feel free to post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are valid, either use the [automatic variable `$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args) (no `param` block needed here):

```bash
& { Write-Host ("Received input: " + $args) } foo bar baz
```

Or a single parameter taking [`ValueFromRemainingArguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefromremainingarguments-argument):

```bash
& {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)] $hey)
    
    Write-Host ("Received input: " + $hey)
} foo bar baz
```

In both cases the array is coerced to a string and joined by [`$OFS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#ofs) (a space by default).

Comment: this is amazing. these are great options to have under the belt and will surely come in handy

Comment: @TiagoDuarte glad you could learn something new :)